# Select distinct active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called Shops with an attribute called brands, brands is a text field and contains multiple brands. What i would like to do is select all unique brands and display them sorted in alphabetic order

```
@brands = Shop.all(:select => 'distinct(brands)')
```

What to do from here?

Comment: Can the field `Shop#brands` hold multiple brands like: "rony, hoke, fike". Or is it just a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Shop#brands` can hold multiple values like for example: "rony, hoke, fike", then I can reluctantly suggest doing something like this:

```
@brands = Shop.all(:select => 'brands').each { |s| 
  s.brands.split(',').map { |b| 
    b.strip.downcase
  }
}.flatten.uniq.sort
```

**BUT**, you should really think about your data model here to prevent such hackery. You couuld break out the brands into it's own table + model and do a many to many relationship with `Shop`.

Comment: Thanks jits, yes you are absolutely right, this is a bad path to be heading. I will do as you suggest.